# React router nested routes v5 with HTTP request

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm using react-router as following in the App.js file:

```
 <Route exact path="/category/:categoryId">
    <ProductLists />
 </Route>
```

and is been called like this:

```
<RouterLink to={`/category/${category.id}`}>
    {category.name}
</RouterLink>
```

But the problem is that when I'm trying to make the HTTP request inside the ProductLists component, it tries to put the "category" in the beginning for the request.

This is the code that makes the request:

```
Axios.get(
`/api/resources/products/category-id/?categoryId=${categoryId}`,
{
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': CONTENT_TYPE_JSON_VALUE,
  },
}
```

So instead of doing this:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/resources/products/category-id/?categoryId=10a49ef4
```

it is doing this:

```
http://localhost:3000/category/api/resources/products/category-id/?categoryId=10a49ef4
```

Any idea why the "category" is inserted at the beginning of the request?

Thanks!

Comment: Where's the code that makes the request?

Comment: I added it to the question @Yousaf

Comment: I think you want the full back-end url in your Axios request. Otherwise, it will try to get it from the front end

Comment: @szczocik That is what I'm doing. All other requests are working fine. only the one with nested routing is giving me hard time.

Comment: Try setting the [baseURL](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config).

Comment: One way is to take the current path, replace the word "categories" from it and then prepend that url string before the backend URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Yousaf I found the answer.

I just had to add baseURL: '/' like this

```
Axios.get(
 `/api/resources/products/category-id/?categoryId=${categoryId}`,
 {
   baseURL: '/',
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': CONTENT_TYPE_JSON_VALUE,
  },
}
```

Hope this will help someone in the future